# How to fix "invalid signature when apt-get update" error?

Tags: linux, apt-get

Whenever I'm trying to `sudo apt-get update` I'm getting these errors:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 Clement Lefebvre (Linux Mint Package Repository v1) <root@linuxmint.com>

W: GPG error: http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 Clement Lefebvre (Linux Mint Package Repository v1) <root@linuxmint.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/rafaela/Release  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So, I did some reading and tried changing mirrors in the sofetware-sources area, and also followed this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97493/invalid-signatures-when-running-apt-get-update), and ran this command:

`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3EE67F3D0FF405B2`

but got this result which didn't help me:

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.joWxQNcMmd --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3EE67F3D0FF405B2
gpg: requesting key 0FF405B2 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 0FF405B2: "Clement Lefebvre (Linux Mint Package Repository v1) <root@linuxmint.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Any idea what else I can try in order to solve it?

p.s It all started when trying to install nodejs and npm.

Comment: i'm getting the eact same  error for rosa (mint 17.3) i've tried everything including deleting the keying and recreating it , nothing helps....

Answer (score 4):

**This worked for me on Linux Mint 17 Qiana:**

sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists

sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-key list | grep expired

> Get the key to use from that result:
>   pub   4096R/**BE1DB1F1** 2011-03-29 [expired: 2014-03-28]

sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net BE1DB1F1

sudo apt-get update

Solution partially from [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/718437/gpg-error-the-following-signatures-were-invalid-keyexpired/718439#718439).

Answer (score -1):

### To fix the `BADSIG` error

It should be `packages.linuxmint.com` not `extra.linuxmint.com`.

Find which package list files contain the offending host:

```
grep -R extra.linuxmint.com /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Change any lines which match.

FYI, my one line was in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` and now reads:

```
deb http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela main
```

If you still have `Hash Sum mismatch` errors, then follow social's steps.

Comment: This does not list NO-PUBKEY but complains that the `gpgv` command fails, instead.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the answer to refer to the OP's BADSIG error and directed to an existing answer for the other errors.